# Centering Nav bar

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to center my nav bar on my website.  I attempted several different ways to do this all failing.  I believe there might be something wrong with my code...  I am not currently using an IDE only notepad if this makes a difference.

Here is the code:

```css
ul#list-nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -540 auto;
  padding: 720;
  width: 1040;
}
ul#list-nav li {
  display: inline
}
ul#list-nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: #F7819F;
  color: #DF013A;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
ul#list-nav li a:hover {
  background: #DF01A5;
  color: #DF01A5;
}
div#nav {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #FF0000;
}
div#nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list-nav">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="bio.htm">Biography</a></li>
  <li><a href="career.htm">Career</a></li>
  <li><a href="links.htm">Links</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="tutorial.htm">Tutorial</a><li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your lengths need units (probably pixels, `px`).

Comment: You can either write `margin` to set vertical then horizontal margins, or `margin-left` to write just the left margin. You appear to be trying to do a mix.

Comment: ok. I had t fix some of my measurements and added the units. still no go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is here

```css
ul#list-nav {
  list-style:none; 
  margin-left: -540 auto; 
  padding:720;
  width: 1040;
}
```

the length always needs a unit to work (except if the value is `0`), otherwise the browser won't process it.

plus you are using the shorthand to `margin-left`, if you want to shortand attributes in this case just use `margin`

See how shorthand works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties)

so, take in consideration your values I think you are using `px`(pixels),

here is how you will center you navbar

```css
ul#list-nav {
  list-style:none; 
  margin:0 auto; 
  width: 1040px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. You can use `margin: 0 auto;` which will center the navigation. Here is the solution:

```css
ul#list-nav {
  list-style:none; 
  margin: 0 auto; /* notice the code here */
  width: 610px; /* notice the code here */
}

ul#list-nav li { 
  display: inline }  

ul#list-nav li a { 
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:5px 0; width:100px;
  background:#F7819F; 
  color:#DF013A; float: left;
  text-align:center; 
  border-left:1px solid #ffffff; }  

ul#list-nav li a:hover {
  background:#DF01A5; 
  color:#DF01A5; } 

div#nav{
  text-align: 
  center; 
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #FF0000;
}
div#nav ul{
  display: inline-block; 
  border-radius: 25px;}
```

```html
<ul id="list-nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="bio.htm">Biography</a></li>
      <li><a href="career.htm">Career</a></li>
      <li><a href="links.htm">Links</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="tutorial.htm">Tutorial</a><li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

We've all been in your shoes, the first tedious project to get a navigation bar to center...I remember those days!  Fortunately its a very easy thing to do once you begin to understand how the browsers renders elements to the DOM.

First up, we need to define some sort of container element, you could use the body, but I normally define an extra "wrapper" to hold my elements.

```css
#navWrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 75px;
    }

    #navContainer {
        width: 200px;
        height: 75px;
        background: black;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<div id="navWrapper">
         <div id="navContainer">
              <nav>...</nav>
         </div> 
    </div>
```

Now lets style this, first off we want our wrapper to fill 100% of the viewport, we then want our nav container to be positioned in the centre of the screen.  To do this, we can allow the browser to calculate the left/right offsets by using `margin:0 auto`, opposed to what you are doing above where you set absolute values (this will generally be bad practice for cross platform compatability).

So the whole css:

```
#navWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
}

#navContainer {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 75px;
    background: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Feel free to change these values as you please, I hope this helps you understand!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```css
ul#list-nav {
  text-align: center;
}
ul#list-nav > li { 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can also remove useless floats.

```css
ul#list-nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
ul#list-nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul#list-nav > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: #F7819F;
  color: #DF013A;
}
ul#list-nav > li > a:hover {
  background: #DF01A5;
  color: #DF01A5;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list-nav">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="bio.htm">Biography</a></li>
  <li><a href="career.htm">Career</a></li>
  <li><a href="links.htm">Links</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="tutorial.htm">Tutorial</a><li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add this property  margin-left:25% and margin-right:25% to the **ul#list-nav**  itz works for all viewport Try this.
```

```css
ul#list-nav {
  list-style: none;
 margin-left:25%;
 margin-right:25%;

  padding: 720;
  width: 1040;
}
ul#list-nav li {
  display: inline
}
ul#list-nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: #F7819F;
  color: #DF013A;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
ul#list-nav li a:hover {
  background: #DF01A5;
  color: #DF01A5;
}
div#nav {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #FF0000;
}
div#nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list-nav">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="bio.htm">Biography</a></li>
  <li><a href="career.htm">Career</a></li>
  <li><a href="links.htm">Links</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="tutorial.htm">Tutorial</a><li>
</ul>
```